# lapply formals over named vs unamed functions in a list

Tags: r, lapply

I'm trying to work out how to combine a number of functions into a new function. I have code that determines which functions should be combined, and stores them in a list. Some of the functions share arguments, so I need to eliminate the duplicates before building the new function. The following works:

```R
fun1 <- function(x, y) x + y
fun2 <- function(y, z) z * y

funlist <- list(fun1, fun2)
args <- unlist(lapply(funlist, formals)) ## "x", "y", "y", "z"
args <- args[unique(names(args))]        ## "x", "y", "z"
```

At this point, args is a list with three named elements, "x", "y", and "z". I can pass this to `as.pairlist()` when I'm building my new function.

However, if the functions in funlist are named, my code breaks:

```
funlist2 <- list(fun1 = fun1, fun2 = fun1)
args2 <- unlist(lapply(funlist2, formals))  ## "fun1.x", "fun1.y", "fun2.y", "fun2.z"
args2 <- args2[unique(names(args2))]  ## "fun1.x", "fun1.y", "fun2.y", "fun2.z"
```

Here, the name of the function is prepended to the arguments, making every argument unique. If I call `formals` on individual list element, this doesn't happen:

```
formals(funlist[[1]])
formals(funlist2[[1]])
## both return the same dotted pair list, $x, $y
```

The list element names only appear when I'm using `lapply`. I can fix this with a temporary list that removes the names from funlist2, but I don't understand why this is happening - why does lapply add names to the output of formals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the output before the `unlist` call:

```
(args2 <- lapply(funlist2, formals))
$fun1
$fun1$x


$fun1$y



$fun2
$fun2$x


$fun2$y
```

`lapply` is putting names back on the top level but the names at the next level down are the same, while `unlist` then concatenates the names at different levels and joins them with periods. In the first instance, `unlist` didn't see any names at the first level and so didn't need to do any concatenation.

Comment: Thanks! It's pretty obvious in retrospect. Not enough caffeine this morning I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be on purpose, but args and args2 are both just named lists without any objects in them... If you were to run your code as such

```
funlist2 <- list(fun1 = fun1, fun2 = fun1)
args2 <- unlist(lapply(funlist2, function(fun) names(formals(fun))))
args2 <- unique(args2)
```

Now you have a vector with the unique variable names.  You can now (if you wish) make the following list:

```
lst <- list()
lenght(lst) <- length(args2)
names(lst) <- args2
```

And together those two blocks of code should be the same as your original code.  I don't have an available kernel to run this on so I can't provide outputs sorry.

Comment: That works, thanks. I still don't understand why this is necessary - that is, why does the output of formals change when called at the top level vs when passed to lapply?

Comment: The output of `formals` doesn't change. Part of `lapply` is that if the input is a named list, the output is a named list.